# Involution element in $\mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_o$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

We know that the groups $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_o$, for $o$ odd is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{2o}$. Now, the elements of $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_o$ can be written as pairs of the form $(i,0)/(i,1)$. My question is, how do we identify the elements of $i,0$ and/ or $i,1$ with that of the cyclic group elements $\{0,1,\ldots,2o-1\}$. Specificlly, how can the involution element of the cyclic group written as? Any hints? Thanks beforehand.

Comment: Did you try it for $o=3$ directly? This should help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main idea here is to use the Chinese remainder theorem. In our case, it states that every number from $x \in Z_{2 \cdot m}$, if $m$ is odd, has a unique representation in the form $(x\mod2\;,  x\mod m)$. this induces an isomorphism of groups.